# How can I get Chinese string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, dialog

I want to convert this to chinese.

I used MFC dialog.

---

\u5DF4\u62C9\u9547

\u73FE\u4EE3\u57CE

---

How can I do? Please help me.

Comment: Are these characters UTF-8 encoded? UTF-16? UTF-32?

Comment: If they are UTF-32 but you pass `CP_UTF8` as the first parameter, then it probably will not work as expected.

Comment: What do you want? To print Chinese text on the screen or output it in file?

Comment: This problem is "Unicode Hex to wchar*"

Comment: I googled some articles but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

MFC natively supports Unicode, using UTF-16. Your characters are all in the BMP, so there's no problem with surrogate characters. You can just pass a literal string `L"\u5DF4\u62C9\u9547\u73FE\u4EE3\u57CE"` to MFC. Of course, when you're building an application for Chinese, you do not use the ANSI functions of MFC.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // declare unicode text in hex code 
 LPCWSTR pszText = (LPCWSTR)"\xF4\x5D\xC9\x62\x47\x95\xFE\x73\xE3\x4E\xCE\x57";

 // display unicode in UNICODE build dialog
 SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, pszText);

 // display unicode text in in MCBS build dialog
 SetDlgItemTextW(this->m_hWnd, IDC_EDIT1, pszText);
```